# Error in Web player due to Spotfire Statistics Services

Tags: tibco, spotfire

when i open dashbaord in web player i am getting following error.

"There is no URL specified for TIBCO Spotfire Statistics Services."

I have checked the box to use locally-installed Enterprise Runtime for engine.

What is the solution for this. Or do anyone have a custom url that i can use to face this issue.

Much appreciated

Comment: can any one help me to understand why this question is not relevant ?

Comment: I didn't down vote you but it was probably by R developers since you tagged R but didn't give any details on how it's related. Anyone who doesn't use Spotfire won't know what the statistics service is for R and I'm 99% sure you can't use R in the web player without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a programming question, hence the down and close votes.

Using the terr engine on the webplayer needs to have a working spofire statistics server. Using the locally-installed terr engine only works for the client software.

Comment: Understood. Thank you